# como puedo hacer esta consulta con hql

Tags: hql

org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 130 [SELECT  VR.ASO_NUMIT,VR.PRO_COD,PM_FECHA_CORTE FROM SIPASDB.SIP_VRESCATE_PROCESO_MORA7 VR INNER JOIN SIPASDB.SIP_PROCESOS_MORA7  ON VR.ASO_NUMIT = ASO_NUMINT  WHERE  PM_ESTADO = 1]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.